# Add a web front end to a winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webserver

I've written a c# .NET winforms application I'm quite happy with.
Now I came to the conclusion, that it would be great to control this app also over the internet.

My idea is to just include a webserver into the EXE that will show the GUI of the app in a webbrowser also.

what would be the easiest way to do so? This is a hobbiest project, so I don't want to pay for commercial solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Markus

Comment: Ideally you would have separated the application logic into a separate assembly that both the WinForms and Web apps can reference. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately or fortunately including a webserver in your EXE is definitely NOT the way to go here.  In fact it won't and can't work that way.

What you need to do is separate out your business logic (the code that does the processing for your application) from your UI (the winforms control parts) in such a way that you can build a web front end that connects to your business logic.  If done properly you can use the same business logic for both UI's.  Your web front end will have to be hosted on a webserver somewhere but a winforms app can't be hosted in a web browser... it just doesn't work like that.

Read up on N-tier programming or the MVC pattern to get started down this direction.